# segmentation fault while using pthreads in class

Tags: c++, pthreads, coredump

I have the follwing code that gets core dumped error. Each C instance creates their own thread then runs. I guess there is something wrong with static function and class argument "count". When I comment out the code that prints it, no fault occurs..

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <pthread.h>
    using namespace std;

    class C {
        public:
        int count;
        C(int c_): count(c_){}
    public:
        void *hello(void)
        {
            std::cout << "Hello, world!" <<std::endl;
            std::cout<<count; // bug here!!!
            return 0;
        }

        static void *hello_helper(void *context)
        {
            return ((C *)context)->hello();
        }

        void run()  {

            pthread_t t;
            pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, NULL);
        }

    };

    int main()  {

    C c(2);
    c.run();

    C c2(4);
    c2.run();

    while(true);

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to write an answer. You were calling `hello_helper` with a `context` of `NULL` based on how you were creating your thread. C++ fully allows you to call member functions on null pointers, and no error occurs unless a member element is accessed.

In your case, by adding the line to print `count`. You are now accessing a member variable on a null pointer, which is a big no-no.

Here's an example of what you were getting away with:

```
#include <iostream>
class Rebel
{
    public:
    void speak()
    {
        std::cout << "I DO WHAT I WANT!" << std::endl;        
    }    
};
int main()
{
    void * bad_bad_ptr = NULL;
    ((Rebel*)bad_bad_ptr)->speak();
}
```

Output:

`I DO WHAT I WANT!`

By modifying your `pthread_create` call to pass the `this` pointer (i.e. `pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, this);`, you now have a valid instance to access member variables on.

Comment: mascoj you are right, that argument is pointer to a class instance, I was sloppy at that point..

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by passing this pointer instead off NULL while creating threads. I guess os created same thread twice int the former case ?

Comment: To make this answer more useful (and less downvote bait) I recommend adding the code that you changed, what you changed it to, and explain how this solved your problem.

Comment: I just changed the line pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, NULL);  with pthread_create(&t, NULL, &C::hello_helper, this); and it worked.

Comment: @eral Because by printing the ````count```` variable you are attempting to access a member of the class ````C````. In this case, since your ````this```` pointer would be ````NULL````, it results in a segfault.

Comment: mascoj you are right, that argument is pointer to a class instance, I was sloppy at that point..